# whole page refresh on map jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, linq

I display map on whole page like this

```
     <div id="map_canvas">

</div>
```

UPDATE 2:
ok now i succesffuly display menu on map but the probelm is when i click on button menu display and then immediately disappear again and also whole map is refresh which i dont want

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

$('#btnmenu').click(function () { $('#menu').show();

}); });

</script>

<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

         <div id="map_canvas">

    </div>
       <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnmenu" runat="server" Text="Menu" />
        </div>

         <div class="tabsleft" id="menu" style="display:none">

    <ul >
    <li>
    <a><img class="imga" alt="dashboard" src="images/eve.bmp" border="0" />DASHBOARD</a>
    </li>

    </ul>
    </div>


    </form>
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just need to modify your script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnmenu').click(function () {
           if ($("#btnmenu").hasClass("active")) {
           $("#btnmenu").removeClass("active");
           }
           else {
                    $("#btnmenu").addClass("active");

                }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: and how to hide menu when i open page.. i do this but this not work .. i add runat=server on div menu id and on page load i code menu.visible=false; and when i try your code this does not work

Comment: sorry you need to hide so remove class active

Comment: so what i add when i remove class active

Comment: but  how to perform action for menu id?

Comment: in your code there is only btnmenu .. i want when i open page then menu must be hide and only buttion display so when i  click on button then want to display menu  ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122077/discussion-between-mirza-obaid-and-user6628729).